# BUG message on xenserver 6.5 - bad memory?

Tags: memory, hardware, xen, kernel, bug

Several times a day I receive the following error in /var/log/messages. The server hangs and requires a reboot to respond again:

```
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166776] BUG: unable to handle kernel   paging request at ffffee00006fb6e0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166789] IP: [<ffffffff8111a8c8>]       get_page_from_freelist+0x2d8/0x530
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166801] PGD 0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166805] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166810] Modules linked in: lockd sunrpc openvswitch(O) gre libcrc32c ipt_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables dm_multipath nls_utf8 isofs dm_mirror video backlight sbs sbshc hed acpi_ipmi ipmi_msghandler nvram sr_mod cdrom hid_generic sg psmouse serio_raw e1000 usb_storage usbhid hid tpm_tis lpc_ich mfd_core i2c_i801 tpm tpm_bios shpchp ehci_pci microcode coretemp scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_hp_sw scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod pata_acpi ata_piix ata_generic libata sd_mod scsi_mod uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166891] CPU: 1 PID: 2914 Comm: xcp-rrdd Tainted: G           O 3.10.0+2 #1
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166897] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./G31M-GS.  , BIOS P1.70 05/28/2010
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166904] task: ffff880024ff1710 ti: ffff8800243be000 task.ti: ffff8800243be000
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166910] RIP: e030:[<ffffffff8111a8c8>]  [<ffffffff8111a8c8>] get_page_from_freelist+0x2d8/0x530
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166919] RSP: e02b:ffff8800243bfae8  EFLAGS: 00010086
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166924] RAX: ffffee00006fb6e0 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffffea00006e1f20
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166928] RDX: ffff88002ea97240 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff88002ea97240
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166933] RBP: ffff8800243bfbb8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000000005b9
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166938] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff8800243bfdb0 R12: ffffea00006fa960
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166943] R13: 00000000000201da R14: ffffea00006e1f00 R15: ffff88002ea97210
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166953] FS:  00007f4e0b8df6e0(0000) GS:ffff88002ea80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166960] CS:  e033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166965] CR2: ffffee00006fb6e0 CR3: 00000000245ca000 CR4: 0000000000002660
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166970] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166975] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166979] Stack:
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166983]  0000000000000002 ffff8800243bffd8 0000000000000001 ffffffff81a98710
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.166991]  ffff880000000041 ffff880020dcd200 0000000000000003 0000000000000000
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167001]  00000001000201da ffffffff81a986c0 0000000000000201 ffffffff81a98710
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167010] Call Trace:
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167017]  [<ffffffff8111b543>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x153/0x890
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167024]  [<ffffffff8107f16a>] ? lg_local_unlock+0x1a/0x20
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167031]  [<ffffffff81182555>] ? mntput_no_expire+0x45/0x150
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167037]  [<ffffffff8111ef81>] ? ra_submit+0x21/0x30
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167044]  [<ffffffff8111f2f1>] ? ondemand_readahead+0x1a1/0x1c0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167051]  [<ffffffff81115b5f>] generic_file_aio_read+0x55f/0x660
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167058]  [<ffffffff811646a7>] do_sync_read+0x97/0xe0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167063]  [<ffffffff81164a21>] vfs_read+0xc1/0x180
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167069]  [<ffffffff81165271>] SyS_read+0x61/0xa0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167076]  [<ffffffff8150ee99>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167080] Code: ff 4d 8d 74 24 e0 85 c0 74 0c 48 8b 7d 90 4c 8b 77 08 49 83 ee 20 49 8d 4e 20 49 8b 56 20 bb 01 00 00 00 48 8b 41 08 48 89 42 08 <48> 89 10 48 b8 00 01 10 00 00 00 ad de 49 89 46 20 48 b8 00 02
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167129] RIP  [<ffffffff8111a8c8>] get_page_from_freelist+0x2d8/0x530
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167135]  RSP <ffff8800243bfae8>
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.167139] CR2: ffffee00006fb6e0
Feb  1 13:44:54 xenserver-abfuqvrs kernel: [35023.170704] ---[ end trace cce0363672e3b240 ]---
```

I thought this may be bad memory so I carried out a memtest against it. 16 passes and it ran for 24hours but did not find any errors.

Does anyone know what else I can try before confirming that this is a bug?

The hard disk is brand new and doesnt show any errors in smart scan.

Also, what is "ffffee00006fb6e0" is this a memory address? If it couldnt get to this address then this would have shown in the memtest right?

Im stuck to what is causing this.

Comment: If there is any more information I can provide please let me know.

Comment: Your BIOS firmware seems to be quite old (BIOS P1.70 05/28/2010). Please update to the most recent version. Furthermore: check if your server is on Citrix XenServer HCL (http://hcl.xensource.com/BrowsableServerList.aspx)

Comment: @Striker_84 My board is ASRock, and it is not on that G31M-GS list. Does this mean I will not be able to use this with stability?

Comment: basically that means that it's not supported or verified for XS 6.5. Citrix would refuse to provide support.

Comment: @Striker_84 thanks - will have to live with it I guess